# Почему перезаписывается словарь?

Tags: python

Из `DataSet` выбираю события, которые произошли **2015** году, и хочу записывать тип `Primary Type` в словарь, чтобы через `class Counter` посмотреть самые популярные.
Как правильно добавлять в словарь, а не перезаписывать значения?

```
import csv
import re
import collections

a = {"Primary Type": set()}

with open("Crimes.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for smt in reader:
        if len(re.findall(r"\w+/\w+/2015\b", smt[2])) > 0:
            a["Primary Type"] = smt[5]
            print(a)

c = collections.Counter(a)
print(c.most_common(3))
```

### Пример того что я получаю на выходе:

```
{'Primary Type': 'ASSAULT'}
{'Primary Type': 'DECEPTIVE PRACTICE'}
{'Primary Type': 'BURGLARY'}
{'Primary Type': 'DECEPTIVE PRACTICE'}
{'Primary Type': 'HOMICIDE'}
{'Primary Type': 'HOMICIDE'}
{'Primary Type': 'HOMICIDE'}
{'Primary Type': 'HOMICIDE'}
{'Primary Type': 'HOMICIDE'}
[('Primary Type', 'HOMICIDE')]  # тут я ожидаю получить HOMICIDE DECEPTIVE PRACTICE и тд.
```

Comment: Потому что вы его перезаписываете в строчке `a["Primary Type"] = smt[5]`

Answer (score 2):

Поправил, сделал так:

```
import csv
import re
import collections

m = []
with open("Crimes.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for smt in reader:
        if len(re.findall(r"\w+/\w+/2015\b", smt[2])) > 0:
            m.append(smt[5])

c = collections.Counter(m)
print(c.most_common(3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Модуль [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) гораздо лучше подходит для решение такого рода задач:

```
import pandas as pd

# читаем данные из CSV в Pandas DataFrame    
filename = r'D:\download\Chicago_Crimes_2012_to_2017.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=0)
# фильтруем данные - оставляем только 2015 год
df = df[df['Date'].str.contains('\d{2}/\d{2}/2015\s')]
```

показываем top-5 наиболее часто встречающихся в выборке за 2015г. преступлений:

```
print(df['Primary Type'].value_counts().head(5))
```

результат:

```
THEFT              57292
BATTERY            48904
CRIMINAL DAMAGE    28669
NARCOTICS          23833
OTHER OFFENSE      17534
Name: Primary Type, dtype: int64
```

тоже самое в виде словаря:

```
print(df['Primary Type'].value_counts().head(5).to_dict())
```

результат:

```
{'THEFT': 57292, 'BATTERY': 48904, 'CRIMINAL DAMAGE': 28669, 'NARCOTICS': 23833, 'OTHER OFFENSE': 17534}
```